# Extracting links from all heading tags using jSoup

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

I am trying to extract links (title and its address)  from all heading tags `<h3>` present in the web page.

Code which I have tried is:

```
String u="http://www.thehindu.com/business/";
Document docu = (Document) Jsoup.connect(u).get();

Elements lnk = docu.select("h3");
  for (Element an : lnk) {
      String s= an.attr("abs:href");

        String name = an.text();
        System.out.println( s);

 }
```

I am not getting any output.
What is the problem?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) What seems to be the problem with your code?

Comment: Get all elements by name h3 and get their link attribute...

Comment: @Pshemo i have now mentioned my code

Comment: Could you post a small HTML sample which demonstrates the problem ?

Comment: Why my question is voted down? As being a beginner, i would like to know is there any thing wrong with my question, which i should change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You selected `h3` and you are trying to read its `href` attribute, but `h3` doesn't have one (there is no `<h3 href="foobar">`). What you want to select is `a` which is placed inside `h3` and read `href` value from it.

So your code should look more like

```
String u = "http://www.thehindu.com/business/";
Document docu = (Document) Jsoup.connect(u).get();

Elements lnk = docu.select("h3 a[href]");
for (Element an : lnk) {
    String s = an.attr("abs:href");
    String name = an.text();

    System.out.println(name);
    System.out.println(s);
    System.out.println("--------");

}
```

Comment: how can i do the same, for all headings inside a particular div tag witha given  id name?

Comment: You need to give some example. Also consider reading http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax

Comment: i have completed my project, that is a speech based web browser using jsoup,freetts and sphinx.